# Uvicorn log the errror message instead of INFO:uvicorn.error:Application

Tags: python, logging, fastapi, uvicorn, asgi

I am trying out uvicorn and whenever the server is run, it says `INFO:uvicorn.error:Application`. How can I see what is causing the error? How do I print the error in the log?

```
» uvicorn serve:app --reload --log-level debug
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [207627] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [207629]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application startup complete.
```

I have tried `log-level` but it doesnt seem to work

```
» uvicorn serve:app --reload --log-level trace
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [207665] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [207667]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Started scope={'type': 'lifespan', 'asgi': {'version': '3.0', 'spec_version': '2.0'}}
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Receive {'type': 'lifespan.startup'}
TRACE:    ASGI [1] Send {'type': 'lifespan.startup.complete'}
TRACE:uvicorn.asgi:ASGI [1] Send {'type': 'lifespan.startup.complete'}
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:uvicorn.error:Application startup complete.
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason you can't find the error is that it's not an error, it is the name of the logger (set in `uvicorn/main.py`):

```
logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error")
```

If you look inside the `startup()` function of that module there is a `logger.info(...` which generates that log message you're seeing using the logger named `uvicorn.error`.

There's an open (at the time of writing it is open) issue about the logger name being confusing (but the good news is it's just a name not an error): https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/562

Answer (score 1):

Ben explained part of the reason. I don't deem a bug of uvicorn, but questioner didn't configure logger correctly.

Uvicorn have some internal loggers like `uvicorn`, `uvicorn:access`, `uvicorn.error`, `uvicorn.asgi`. And `uvicorn.error` logger propagates the msg by default.

`INFO:     Application startup complete.` is logged by `uvicorn.error` logger.
`INFO:uvicorn.error:Application startup complete.` is logged by some parent logger, probably `root` handler.

The solution is to stop a msg handled by two logger.

1. Stop setting up handler for parent logger, probably `root` logger. (preferred)
2. **Or** Disable `uvicorn.error` propagating.

   ```py
   logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.error")
   logger.propagate = False
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I created another solution for this. I created a class NameFilter which filter out the different logger names and rename them directly.

logger.py > Usage

```
name_filter = NameFilter()
console_handler.addFilter(name_filter)
```

logger.py > Class

```
class NameFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.name == 'uvicorn.error':
            record.name = 'fastapi'
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the formatter. For example, it's possible to start uvicorn with parameter:  `--log-config=log_conf.yaml`

and your log_conf.yaml:

```
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
  default:
    format: '%(asctime)s - uvicorn - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  access:
    format: '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
handlers:
  default:
    formatter: default
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stderr
  access:
    formatter: access
    class: logging.StreamHandler
    stream: ext://sys.stdout
loggers:
  uvicorn.error:
    level: INFO
    handlers:
      - default
    propagate: no
  uvicorn.access:
    level: INFO
    handlers:
      - access
    propagate: no
root:
  level: DEBUG
  handlers:
    - default
  propagate: no
```

notice how the format is declared for default logger.

Now my log (in docker) is like:

```
services_1  | 2024-01-25 21:22:11,025 - uvicorn - INFO - Waiting for application startup.
services_1  | 2024-01-25 21:22:11,026 - uvicorn - INFO - Application startup complete.
services_1  | 2024-01-25 21:22:11,034 - uvicorn - INFO - Started server process [23]
```